# Excel VBA can't open Workbook downloaded from Google Drive

Tags: excel, vba, drive

My program won't open a workbook due to an error in the file downloaded from google drive (I have no other way to obtain the date except from GD). When I run my macro, a msg box saying "Excel VBA can't open Workbook" pops up, and when I try to open the source file , the following error is shown:

"We found a problem in some content in 'Planilha1.xlsx'. Would you like us to try to recover the most we can?. If you trust the workbook source, click yes"

Error when I open the data source workbook

[image]

Te bugged part of my code:

```
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1_1 = wb1.Worksheets("Auto")

ws1_1.Activate

sPasta = ws1_1.Cells(2, 3).Value
sPasta = sPasta & "\"
sArquivo = ws1_1.Cells(7, 3).Value
**Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(sPasta & sArquivo, False)**
```

It simply stops there, in the last line. I've already checked if it's pulling the right workbook's name from the right cell, and everything is OK. The problem is really in the drive-downloaded file. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Ps.: when I repair the workbook, the macro runs perfectly

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `VBA` to repair the file on opening so it won't stop your Macro.

On your last line change from this:

```
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(sPasta & sArquivo, False)
```

To this:

```
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(sPasta & sArquivo, UpdateLinks:=False, corruptload:=xlrepairfile)
```